# How to hard code / embed subtitles of videos inside a folder with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, video-encoding

Lets say I have folder A with lots of videos that have TX3G subtitles

Some videos don't have any subtitles

So I need a windows command to process all videos inside this folder and embed / hard code this subtitles

This command may overwrite the existing file or copy them inside to another folder both are fine

Thank you so much for any help

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/1287482/19943